# Insert into another table where the columns exist in table 2

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to insert the values of table 1 into table 2, where the columns in table 2 exist in table 1. For more reference see this tables:

Table 1

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|  col_1   |  col_2   |   col_3  |
+----------+----------+----------+
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Table 2

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  col_1   |  col_2   |   col_3  |  col_4   |  col_5   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |          |          |
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |          |          |
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |          |          |
| col_val  | col_val  | col_val  |          |          |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

If the columns in table 2 doesn't exist in table 1 it inserts null value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: insert in dynamic way

Comment: Which columns from table 1 are going into which columns in table 2?

Comment: col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 and col_5 are names of columns. So table_1.col_1 goes to table_2.col_1, table_1.col_2 goes to table_2.col_2 same in col_3

Comment: Show your php code of insertion.

Comment: i don't have, i'm just asking if that's possible in an easy way

Comment: I don't feel you've made it clear if you want your answer in PHP or in SQL, and what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: in SQL if possible, but if not probably in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("yourhost", "username", "password", "your_db");
if(!$con){
    //error    
}

$query1="select * from table1 limit 1";
$query2="select * from table2 limit 1";

$result1=mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$result2=mysqli_query($con, $query2);


if(!$result2 || !$result1){
    //query error    
}

$table1_columns=array_keys(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1));
$table2_columns=array_keys(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2));

$intesection=array_intersect($table1_columns, $table2_columns);


if(is_array($intesection) && !empty($intesection)){
    $query="insert into table2 (";
    foreach($intesection as $column){
        $query.=" $column,";
    }

    $query=substr($query, 1,-1); //to remove the last comma
    $query.=") select ";

    foreach($intesection as $column){
        $query.=" $column,";
    }
    $query=substr($query, 1,-1); //to remove the last comma
    $query.=" from table1 ;";    
}

echo $query; //check the query
```

Comment: thank you very much mister, this code works thumbsup for Mr.Bere

Comment: I just did. Sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value for col 4 & col 5 to NULL and then run this query :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table2;
```

It should work but you have to explicitly specify the columns in common between the two tables.

Comment: i want it to insert in a dynamic way where i won't be specifying column names, let's say i have MAIN_TABLE, then i have 4 or 5 sub tables

Comment: In that case, I think you will need to try smthg with INFORAMTION_SCHEMA table. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445680/2119117 or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx